# Django trigger some code on all instances

Tags: django

I need to execute some code in all running instances of Django (eg.  processes under uwsgi), but have no idea how to make it in a clear way.

Non-working ideas: Celery executes code in the separate process. An adding some middleware which checks some data in the database looks ugly (in other words another caching layer). Restarting process looks ugly too and needs something which actually communicates and performs the restart.

A bit of context, why I need it: have dynamic settings and some locally (in the scope of one process) cached vars in third-party libraries, so when these vars (values on which they depend) are changed I need to reread them in all "djangos".

Comment: What sort of code do you need to run? Each Django process should be completely stateless - what do you need to do such that each process needs to be notified? Sounds like you're trying to store some state on the thread or something.

Comment: Call already coded function :) More of context: have languages section in settings, when I change it on the fly I also need to reset some vars (manually set new values) in third-party modules which read settings on the startup and work only with copied data.

"Each Django process should be completely stateless - what do you need to do such that each process needs to be notified?" Notify each process that settings were changed.

I understand that situation shouldn't exist in general, but it has happened and I need to find a solution.

Comment: Your best bet is just restarting uWSGI. Why is that not an option? If it's a concern about downtime, use a chain restart.